# SwiftUI Newbie: Binding, Toggles, and Fatal Error: Index out of range

Tags: swift, swiftui

Very new to SwiftUI & Swift, and trying to wrap my head around bindings.

Specifically, I have a ForEach loop for `Tasks` that displays a new `TaskRow` of `Tasks`. That task row has two actions:

- A button to delete the task displayed in the relevant row
- A toggle to change the state of a task from 'completed' to 'not completed'

Without the toggle, whenever I delete a task the view updates just fine. But with the toggle present, deleting a task throws a:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

error.

I assume this relates to the `$isSet` binding to self.$data, but I don't know how else to pass that data in a way that the Toggle will update. Code below, thoughts deeply appreciated:

## TaskList.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct TaskList: View {
    @ObservedObject private var data = TaskData()
    @State private var showFinished: Bool = false

    
    var visibleTasks: [Task] {
        data.tasks.filter { task in
            showFinished || !task.finished
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
     
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $showFinished) {
                Text("Show Finished")
            }
            
            ForEach(data.tasks.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    TaskRow(
                            isSet: self.$data.tasks[index].finished,
                            task: self.data.tasks[index],
                            onChange: { self.data.save() },
                            onDelete: { self.deleteTask(task_index: index)})
                
                    Divider()
                }
            AddTask(data: data)
        
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            data.load()
        }
        
    }
    
    func deleteTask(task_index: Int) {
        self.data.tasks.remove(at: self.data.tasks[task_index].id)
    }
}
```

## TaskRow.swift

import SwiftUI

```
struct TaskRow: View {
    @Binding var isSet: Bool
    @State var task: Task
    var onChange: () -> ()
    var onDelete: () -> ()
  
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Toggle("", isOn: $isSet)
                .onChange(of: isSet) { _isOn in
                   onChange()
            }
            Text(task.name)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: onDelete) {
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
            }
        }
        .scaledToFit()
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look at the Demystify SwiftUI video from WWDC 2021. You have a few little mistakes.

Comment: Hi PlankTon, cn you please make the data not a private var, but a var? Then check if data.tasks.indices still is not updated.

Comment: @MacUserT why do you think it can change anything?

Comment: Forget it, it doesn't. Still, an ObservedObject is a var, not a private var.

Comment: @MacUserT it can be private easily if you don't need to generate optional initializer parameter for this var.

Comment: Can you check the number of indices, after you deleted a task. I guess, this is still the old number of indices and not one less.

Comment: The problem with `private` in `@ObservedObject` is that it is being used incorrectly. It shouldn't be `private` because it should be initialized with an `init` parameter. It is unsafe to initialize an `ObservableObject` in a `View` like this.  [The only safe way to do it is using `@StateObject`.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app) This way it is likely leaking and it will definitely create an unstable `View`. The error is because the OP is using `indices` in the loop which is mentioned in Demystify SwiftUI Apple also considers this unsafe

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you enumerate by `indexes` and then get bindings by index inside `ForEach`. This is not safe, because of incorrect ids during state update. I created `ForEachIndexed` for such cases:

```
struct ForEachIndexed<Data: RandomAccessCollection, RowContent: View, ID: Hashable>: View, DynamicViewContent where Data.Index: Hashable {
    var data: [(Data.Index, Data.Element)] {
        forEach.data
    }

    let forEach: ForEach<[(Data.Index, Data.Element)], ID, RowContent>

    init(_ data: Binding<Data>,
         @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Index, Binding<Data.Element>) -> RowContent
    ) where
    Data.Element: Identifiable,
    Data.Element.ID == ID,
    Data: MutableCollection {
        forEach = ForEach(
            Array(zip(data.wrappedValue.indices, data.wrappedValue)),
            id: \.1.id
        ) { i, _ in
            rowContent(i, Binding(get: {
                data.wrappedValue[i]
            }, set: {
                data.wrappedValue[i] = $0
            }))
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        forEach
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ForEachIndexed($data.tasks) { index, taskBinding in
    TaskRow(
        isSet: taskBinding.finished,
        task: taskBinding.wrappedValue,
        onChange: { self.data.save() },
        onDelete: { self.deleteTask(task_index: index)})

    Divider()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 15, you can do the following:

```
ForEach(Array($data.tasks.enumerated()), id: \.element.wrappedValue) { (index, $task) in
    TaskRow(
        isSet: $task.finished,
        task: task,
        onChange: { self.data.save() },
        onDelete: { self.deleteTask(task_index: index) }
    )

    Divider()
}
```

For iOS 14, you get the warning below (and others):

> Conformance of 'Binding' to 'Sequence' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer